# how do I enter multiple keywords and phrase in google adwords

Tags: google, keywords, google-ads

As an example, how would I enter the following key words in google adwords/keywords tab:
Best guaranteed "jump rope" -free

For example, I would want to get any googler who entered anything similar to the following...

best guaranteed jumprope
top guaranteed jump ropes
Best jump ropes with guarantees

..and NOT get the anything like the following..

best jump ropes
top free jump ropes

Note the terms are fictional but in general what I want to do is have two critical adjectives (ex: "best" and "guaranteed") a critical two-word phrase (ex: "jump rope") and a critical negative keyword (ex: -free)

How exactly would this need to appear in the key word screen?
I am a little confused because there is a Phrase Match but that seems to make the whole textbox a phrase rather than just one component within the textbox a phrase.
And there are multiple textboxes.  And a separate section for negative key words but also a negative symbol which implies no need for a negative keywords section.

is this right?

+best +guaranteed +jump +rope -free
(do I select broad or exact match?)

Thx

Comment: Have you called Google AdWords support for this? They are really pretty helpful especially since you're spending money with them.

Answer (score 1):

To enter in multiple keywords in Keyword Planner in the Tools and Analysis menu,

- Click on the Search for new keyword and ad group ideas section.

  - Put the quotes around "jump rope" and leave the rest unquoted as you like.
- Enter in Best Guaranteed "Jump Rope" into the "Your Products or Services" text box.
- To add your negative keyword "free" find the "Targeting Section" and click on "Negative keywords"
- Type in free (no need of the dash, or quotes)
- Click on "Get Ideas"

This will give you a list of search terms you can bid on in an ad campaign without using the word "free." Also note that the results will show "jump rope" in that order (side by side with "jump" coming first) and without the quotes.

When making your list of keywords for bidding on, you can use all the variations of "jump rope" that suits your goals. You can then choose a "phrase match" for the variations you choose.

Perhaps you will want to use assemble the list of keywords first, for example the list of keywords maybe:

"best jump rope"

"best jump ropes"

"jumping rope"

"jump rope"

"jump rope workout"

"jump ropes"

Go to your Campaing's Ad group in question.

- Click the "+ Keywords" button
- Paste in the list (with the quotes, this will make these terms Phrase Matches)
- You may want to choose phrase match for now and adjust as needed as the campaign progresses
- Another option is to use broad match.
- If you use the "+" and "-" google may think that those symbols are a part of the search term
- Scroll down to the bottom of the screen and find "Negative Keywords"
- Click the "+" box to expand it
- Click the "Add" button
- Type in free (no quotes, no dash)

  - That will make free broad negative search term
  - This should keep your ads from showing up when ever "free" is a part of the user's search.